# Issue getting .env to work on Netlify. Nuxt Netlify .env

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

Issue getting `.env` to work on `Netlify`.

My repo is here:
[nuxt-axios-sheets](https://github.com/erichodges/Nuxt-axios-sheets)

I'm getting `key=undefined` in the browser console:
`Failed to load resource`: the server responded with a status of `400` ()

- This is a `Nuxt` project (1.4.2).
- I'm using `dotenv 1.1.1`.
- It works on my local machine.
- I set up the key/value on the `Netlify` dashboard.
- I set up the google sheets api for the Netlify URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since your .env file is not on your Github repo and **it should not be there**,  you have to read the environment variables of Netlify using `process.env` or with a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/getenv .

Comment: Thanks, I did get this working, but forgot about the post here.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you just need to define Environment Variables under the 'Site settings > Build & deploy > Environment > Environment variables'.